# How to align properly center the social footer and footer menu?

Tags: html, css, center, footer

How to align properly center the social footer and footer menu? I tried to align the social footer in three lines, in the 1st line is the icons and the 2nd and 3rd lines are the text at the bottom. But when I re-size the screen the icons are misbehave.

While the footer menu, I want to displayed on one line only. I want to remain the design of footer to all mobile devices no matter what screen size they are.

Here's the link: http://mobiletest.me/google_nexus_6/2507045 and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0za7edhw/)

Here's the CSS for media queries

```
.hcsocialslitwitter, .hcsocialslifb, .hcsocialslilinked, .hcsocialslics, .hcsocialslic{ margin: 0 !important; width: 30%; }
.hcsocials{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.hcsocialspfb{ margin: 1px 0 19px -90px !important; }
.hcsocialspcollections, .hcsocialspcustomer, .hcsocialsptwitter, .hcsocialsplinked{ margin: 1px 0 19px -80px !important; }
.bottom-menu{ float: none; margin: -20px 100px 5px auto; }
.copyrighttext{ margin: -45px 0 0 170px; float: left; }
.footerimg{ margin: 10px 0 0 70px; }
.footer #middle-footer{ padding: 20px 0 10px 0; }
```

Comment: It would be great if you share your footer code in jsfiddle.

Comment: pls see updated post @Dhwani91

Comment: I think your best bet is to setup each social media link in a seperate div with "text-align: center" then place each of those divs in one line. Then your text and icons wont move around?

Comment: @Jesse but if i do that, the original design of my footer will be affected. since, the design of the footer is different to mobile version

Comment: I modified your code last night in Dreamweaver and used percentages with the width of each div. Made things line up fine. I will send you the end product in about 4 hours when I'm back from work

Answer (score 1):

Using media queries should fix it.

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

if you don't know how check out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: yes, i know but i want to remain the design of the footer to all mobile devices and tablets. the code above is for the media queries

Comment: You can do that with multiple queries. In each one you just have to shrink down the size of the images and maybe text. The layout will stay the same. It may seem like a lot of work, but thats how I learned to create a responsive site. Another approach would be to use "em" instead of pixels.